# <a> Links to open in new overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

Hi I have a overlay which has links in it.

Is it possible to get these links to open into another overlay on top because I want the original page with the links to stay open and not navigate to the clicked linked website?

**_blank** and **popup** options in the  tag do not work because it's a standalone program and just makes the original overlay navigate to the clicked link.

Html or javascript it would have to be.

This is how it is at the moment

```
    replaceBBCodeUrl: function(content, attribute) {
    var url, regExpUrl, link;
    if(attribute)
        url = attribute.replace(/\s/gm, this.encodeText(' '));
    else
        url = this.stripBBCodeTags(content.replace(/\s/gm, this.encodeText(' ')));
    regExpUrl = new RegExp(
        '^(?:(?:http)|(?:https)|(?:ftp)|(?:irc)):\\/\\/',
        ''
    );
    if(!url || !url.match(regExpUrl))
        return content;

    this.inUrlBBCode = true;
    link = '<a href="'
            + url
            + '" onclick="window.open(this.href , popup); return false;">'
            + this.replaceBBCode(content)
            + '</a>';
    this.inUrlBBCode = false;
    return link;
},

replaceBBCodeImage: function(url) {
    var regExpUrl, maxWidth, maxHeight, link;
    if(this.settings['bbCodeImages']) {
        regExpUrl = new RegExp(
            this.regExpMediaUrl,
            ''
        );
        if(!url || !url.match(regExpUrl))
            return url;
        url = this.stripTags(url.replace(/\s/gm, this.encodeText(' ')));
        maxWidth = this.dom['chatList'].offsetWidth-50;
        maxHeight = this.dom['chatList'].offsetHeight-50;
        link =  '<img class="bbCodeImage" style="max-width:'
                + maxWidth
                + 'px; max-height:'
                + maxHeight
                + 'px;" src="'
                + url
                + '" alt="" onload="ajaxChat.updateChatlistView();"/>';
        if(!this.inUrlBBCode) {
            link =  '<a href="'
                    + url
                    + '" onclick="window.open(this.href , popup); return false;">'
                    + link
                    + '</a>';
        }
        return link;
    }
    return url;
},
replaceHyperLinks: function(text) {
    var regExp;
    if(!this.settings['hyperLinks']) {
        return text;
    }
    regExp = new RegExp(
        '(^|\\s|>)((?:(?:http)|(?:https)|(?:ftp)|(?:irc)):\\/\\/[^\\s<>]+)(<\\/a>)?',
        'gm'
    );
    return text.replace(
        regExp,
        // Specifying an anonymous function as second parameter:
        function(str, p1, p2, p3) {
            // Do not replace URL's inside URL's:
            if(p3) {
                return str;
            }
            return  p1
                    + '<a href="'
                    + p2
                    + '" onclick="window.open(this.href , popup); return false;">'
                    + p2
                    + '</a>';
        }
    );
},
```

This is all the link related code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps looking for the `a[target]`-attribute? You can find amazing documentation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target)

Comment: nope as stated _blank doesn't work and none of the other options for the target attribute also

Answer (score 0):

You should really consider using ajax for this, for example:

```
$("#yourlink").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: $(this).attr('href')
    }).done(function(data) {
        $('#youroverlay').html(data);
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Why did you use `return false;` at the end?

Comment: Thanks. This is for AJax chat so there are a few more thing which dictate how the links are displayed. So more code would probably have to be rewrote to make it work :(

Comment: @lonut: For good measure. The preventDefault should be sufficient.

Comment: @mhu, I know, that's why I was asking. :)